# Riesz representation theorem: Does the order matter?

Tags: functional-analysis, linear-transformations, hilbert-spaces, dual-spaces, riesz-representation-theorem

Let $X$ be a Hilbert space.

$J:X\rightarrow X',\hspace{1cm}J(x):=(\cdot,x)$

is a complex conjugated isometric isomorphism between $X$ and it's dual space $X'$.

Would there be any problems as a result of changing the definition to $J(x):=(x,\cdot)$  ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the case of complex scalars $J(x)=(x,.)$ would not define  a linear map on $X$ for fixed $x$. It would be conjugate linear.